# How to disable query to turn on disabled command?

Tags: key-bindings, mouse, commands

I have this in my `.emacs` file to disable mouse right clicks:

```
(put 'mouse-save-then-kill 'disabled "mouse-save-then-kill disabled\n")
```

How can I now disable the query generated by emacs to turn this command back on ("`Do you want to use this command anyway? You can now type [y/n/SPC/!]`") ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in your init file:

```
(setq disabled-command-function 'ignore)
```

By default, disabling a command means that you get that prompt when you try to use it.

But you can override this design by setting variable `disabled-command-function` to a function other than its default value, `disabled-command-function`.

You can see the code for disabling and enabling in library `novice.el`.  You can find this out for yourself by doing `C-h f disable-command` and clicking the link to go to the file.

See also the Emacs manual, node [Disabling](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Disabling.html).

Any non-`nil` value for property `disabled` for symbol `mouse-save-then-kill` means that that command is disabled. A `nil` value means that that command is enabled (is not disabled).  But your use of a non-`nil` value does not mean that *mouse right-clicking* is disabled. It means only that command `mouse-save-then-kill` is disabled. It so happens that a right-click invokes that command by default.

Answer (score 5):

Drew's answer solves your stated question so I would suggest accepting that; but my best guess is that something like this is what you're *actually* after:

```
(global-set-key [remap mouse-save-then-kill] 'ignore)
```

(to effectively disable all bindings for that command)

or maybe just:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "<mouse-3>"))
```

(to remove just that specific binding)

or a more extreme approach:

```
(defalias 'mouse-save-then-kill 'ignore)
```

(to completely redefine the command, ensuring that it never does anything, no matter how it's called)

Comment: @Drew answers my question directly but yours is better for the behavior that I actually wanted.